# CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

To connect to BLE devices I am using the code you can find here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828315/1565181

I am running the code on my macpro with bluetooth activated. I can connect to my cell phone in the settings-> blue tooth menu but unfortunately when I run the code I only get the "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform" output on the console. I do not have a developer account yet, can this be the problem?

Comment: What version of MacPro ? I guess that your MacPro has "Classical Bluetooth", but not Bluetooth Low-Energy.

Comment: How are you running the code on your Mac? Is it in a Mac app, or are you running it in the iOS Simulator?

Comment: @Larme: First sorry, I have a macbook pro. It's the newest model.

Comment: @Vinny: I run it in the iOS Simulator

Comment: If you run on the Simulator, you can't use BLE. You have to use it on real device.

Comment: Thx Larme. Therefore I need a developer account right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CoreBluetooth isn't supported in the iOS Simulator. You'll need to run the app on an iOS device that supports Bluetooth LE. You will need a paid developer account in order to run apps on the iOS device.

Comment: Currently, there's no need of paid account, if you install the app on your phone connected via USB to the developer's computer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you need only a real device.
Apple allows debugging for any apple id